# Microsoft access database to java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I am considering using a Microsoft access database for a Java project. My question is, if I use a Microsoft access database and I complete my project and run it as a jar file on any computer/operating system, does any computer/ operating system need to have Microsoft access installed on it, particularly if the database needs to be put on a GUI on the java program and the administrator of the program can add and remove entries.

Comment: i think all you will need to have a functional ODBC support on the OS where the jar is running.

Comment: You can keep your DB in single server and use ODBC datasource to connect to db, thats it..

Comment: As far as I know the jdbc-odbc way is used to access db files. Do, ODBC datasources should be configured separately.

Comment: You'll need to connect to the file through ODBC. If you are considering Access simply to embed it in your application, you may also consider something like: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html.

Comment: Don't! Use a real RDMBS! If you need something leighweight go with H2 or HSQLDB.

Comment: You do not need Access installed to use Jet / ACE, the back-end database that is used by Access. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install the access odbc driver on any machine that accesses the database.  I think you can do this by installing the Access runtime stuff without installing all of Access.  Keep in mind that this sort of data-access is file-level, so your performance will be very poor.  I'd suggest that you use a real database (postgres, mysql, sql server, oracle) or maybe a lightweight one such as [SQL Server express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) and then accessing that database using either an odbc-jdbc bridge or preferably a native jdbc driver.  Using a native jdbc driver will let you run your app from a non-windows environment.

Comment: It may not be poor. It all depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Access Database via the [JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) on every Microsoft Windows system without to install Microsoft Access. You only need the Access Database Engine (ACE) formerly known as [Jet Database Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine). ACE is part of current Windows versions. For older ones it may be necessary to install the [Microsoft Data Access Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components) (MDAC).

Using a Access Database from Java has some disadvantages:

- This is a type 1 driver with native code. Generally pure Java JDBC drivers are more performant.
- With JDK 6 the JDBC-OLE bridge was somewhat [enhanced](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html). But there are still some problems with charsets and CLOBs.
- Your application is restricted to Microsoft Windows operating systems.
- According to the [JDK 7 JDBC-ODBC bridge guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) the JDBC-ODBC bridge will be removed in JDK 8:

> The JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution; it will be removed in JDK 8. In addition, Oracle does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. Oracle recommends that you use JDBC drivers provided by the vendor of your database instead of the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

So if there is any chance to use another database for your project, you should avoid using Microsoft Access together with Java.

There are lots of alternatives with far more better JDBC drivers.

If you want a small footprint embedded database, there are:

- [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) (part of the JDK), also known as [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- [H2](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) e.g. with [Xerial driver](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC)

(Java DB, H2 and HSQLDB are pure Java solutions)

If you prefer a client server solution, for most commercial and open source there exist full-fledged JDBC drivers.

- [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/overview/index.html)
- [Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx) (the server has to run on Windows but your Java client can run on every OS that supports a JVM. See [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server Support Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/data/ff928484))
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)
- [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)