# the use of mySQL and MS access DB for a java application with just a single data table

Tags: java, mysql, swing, ms-access, netbeans

I am developing a simple desktop application that 
  uses the java swing for the interface design with the NetBeans IDE
The system is suppose to have just one table 
with fields that will be accessed via the interface.

Iam considering creating the database with mySQL or microsoft access DB
 I am conversant with the mysql but new to the microsoft access DB

my concern is that creating just a single table with the mySQL database 
  will be kind of wasteful as compared to creating the single table in MS access 
   and connecting the swing interface to the database.

Will be glad if someone can compare the two databases 
for the best option to my situation

thank you all

Comment: Why would it be wasteful in MySQL, and not in Access? Maybe you should consider embedded, full-Java databases, which would make it easier than both of these solutions.

Comment: Isuppose you talking about java Derby DB JBNizet

Comment: Derby is one of the possible choices, yes. But there are others: H2, HSQLDB, etc.

Comment: Access would certainly be wasteful if the user of your application didn't have Access, and had to purchase a license for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You consider to use MySQL, a client server database, or MS Access an embeddable desktop database.

I think you should first think about client server database vs. embeddable database. Does it make sense for your application to store the data on a centralized database server? Will there be many instances of your application running on different clients and will they all access the same data? Or should every application instance have only access to its private data?

If you decide to use a client server database then you can go with MySQL.

If you decide that an embeddable database is enough, then you should know, that Java and MS Access are not known for best cooperation. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221796/microsoft-access-database-to-java/14223891#14223891).

There are some all Java embedded databases like [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) which work very well for desktop applications. You should consider one of these for your project.